# 'FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory' after renaming files

Tags: python, image, operating-system, copy

I'm new to Python, and am trying to copy photos (.jpg) to a folder after renaming the images in numerical order. I have written the following script to rename all the photos in my directory (all 32,000 of them) to what they are (weeds):

```
import os
os.chdir('E:\\weeds')
i=1
for file in os.listdir():
    src=file
    dst="weed"+str(i)+".jpg"
    os.rename(src,dst)
    i+=1
```

Here's a sample of the output naming:

[image]

I am then trying to copy the first 250 of these photos into a new directory, as shown below:

```
import os, shutil

#Copying files to folders
original_weed = 'E:\\weeds'
train_weed = 'E:\\weeds_train'

#Training dataset: Weeds
fnames = ['weed{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(250)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_weed, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_weed, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

The following error is produced:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f08fff292dd8> in <module>
     17     src = os.path.join(original_weed, fname)
     18     dst = os.path.join(train_weed, fname)
---> 19     shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

~\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    259         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    260     else:
--> 261         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    262             # macOS
    263             if _HAS_FCOPYFILE:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\weed0.jpg'
```

What do I need to do so that I can get the file to be identified for copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code - the first part of the script names pictures with index starting from 1:

```
os.chdir('E:\\weeds')
i=1
for file in os.listdir():
```

While the next part of the code iterates through the result of the `range` function, which starts at 0 and ends in 249 in your case. Check the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) for the `range` function for further info.

The error which you got indicates that there is no file named `weed0.jpg` in the directory, which is indeed true.

The easiest fix you can do is to set the initial value of `i` to 0 in the first part of the code, and it should work properly.

Comment: Or modify the `range()` to start at 1 instead of 0.